# how to remove 0 before single number date in js flatpickr?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date-formatting, flatpickr

The js code given below:

```
var endDatePicker = flatpickr("#end-date-picker", {
  enableTime: false,
  singleDate: true,
  selectForward: false,
  dateFormat: "M d, Y",
  onChange: function(selectedDates, dateStr, instance) {
    document.getElementById("end-str-date").innerHTML = dateStr;
  }
});

// Set calendar for table field
  
var StartDatePicker = flatpickr("#beg-date-picker", {
  enableTime: false,
  singleDate: true,
  selectForward: false,
  dateFormat: "m/d/Y",
  year: "numeric",
  month: "1-digit",
  day: "1-digit",
  onChange: function(selectedDates, dateStr, instance) {
    document.getElementById("beg-str-date").innerHTML = dateStr;
  }
});
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cxuqe.jpg)

I want to do this format without 0 before single number day/month date.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DLYG.jpg)

But it show like that, with zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the format from `m/d/Y` to `n/j/Y`.

You can read more about it [in the official documentation](https://flatpickr.js.org/formatting/), but I'll post it here as well:

| Character | Description | Example |
| --- | --- | --- |
| d | Day of the month, 2 digits with leading zeros | 01 to 31 |
| D | A textual representation of a day | Mon through Sun |
| l (lowercase 'L') | A full textual representation of the day of the week | Sunday through Saturday |
| j | Day of the month without leading zeros | 1 to 31 |
| J | Day of the month without leading zeros and ordinal suffix | 1st, 2nd, to 31st |
| w | Numeric representation of the day of the week | 0 (for Sunday) through 6 (for Saturday) |
| W | Numeric representation of the week | 0 (first week of the year) through 52 (last week of the year) |
| F | A full textual representation of a month | January through December |
| m | Numeric representation of a month, with leading zero | 01 through 12 |
| n | Numeric representation of a month, without leading zeros | 1 through 12 |
| M | A short textual representation of a month | Jan through Dec |
| U | The number of seconds since the Unix Epoch | 1413704993 |
| y | A two digit representation of a year | 99 or 03 |
| Y | A full numeric representation of a year, 4 digits | 1999 or 2003 |
| Z | ISO Date format | 2017-03-04T01:23:43.000Z |

Check the working example, as well.

```js
var endDatePicker = flatpickr("#end-date-picker", {
  enableTime: false,
  singleDate: true,
  selectForward: false,
  dateFormat: "M d, Y",
  onChange: function(selectedDates, dateStr, instance) {
    document.getElementById("end-str-date").innerHTML = dateStr;
  }
});

// Set calendar for table field
  
var StartDatePicker = flatpickr("#beg-date-picker", {
  enableTime: false,
  singleDate: true,
  selectForward: false,
  dateFormat: "j/n/Y",
  year: "numeric",
  month: "1-digit",
  day: "1-digit",
  onChange: function(selectedDates, dateStr, instance) {
    document.getElementById("beg-str-date").innerHTML = dateStr;
  }
});
```

```html
<head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/flatpickr/dist/flatpickr.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://npmcdn.com/flatpickr/dist/themes/dark.css">
        <script src="https://npmcdn.com/flatpickr/dist/flatpickr.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://npmcdn.com/flatpickr/dist/l10n/ru.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="datepicker">
  <input type="text" id="end-date-picker">
    <input type="text" id="beg-date-picker">
</div>
<span id="end-str-date"></span>
<br>
<span id="beg-str-date"></span>
</body>
```

Comment: Very informative solution. Thanks a lot.